# Making django app_list avaible for all admin template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I am trying to override django admin template in other to create new layout using bootstrap4.

I need to get app_list on every template of the admin to form the sidebar menu. So far I am able to create the menu for the landing page (admin/index.html) alone and not for the other pages ... Since the app_list tag is not available for them.

**Note the app_list is suppose to list all apps and models under them.**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1921/
Though it is for python 2.7 because of the list.sort().
I had to change it to sorted() to be compatible with python3.x, then looped through the tuple in the django template.